# What is the easiest way to have a default "Good" lighting setup for cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light

Can I have a not too dark scene in Cycles at Startup?
Because I'm not so good at lighting. Two I don't want to mess with it every time. Three I want to have a Quick Way of seeing how my model looks in Cycles.
The lighting Setup at start is great in programs like Keyshot and Marmoset Toolbag; you can load every model in it and it will look good from the start.

Comment: Every Blender artist should read Ben Simonds article, [Lighting Tips From the Masters](http://bensimonds.com/2010/06/03/lighting-tips-from-the-masters/).

Comment: yes i know when i need serious lightning at the final render then ill make serious lightning but before that i need quick results ya know ?

Comment: See: http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/74897

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually keep some generic lights on a hidden layer in my default .blend, so I can just enable that layer to get an instant light setup.

To do this:

1. Open a new file (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>)
2. Create your light setup:

   [image]

   Here are some [good tips on lighting](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/6-tips-for-better-lighting/).

   There are also some nice [light setups in the community](http://www.blendernation.com/2014/08/12/studio-lighting-setup-cycles/) if you don't want to make your own.
3. Move the lights to another layer (<kbd>M</kbd>), then save the startup .blend (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>).

   This will save the current file as how blender will start up by default, so make sure everything is how you want it (visible layers, selected objects, view orientation, etc.)

---

Another thing you can do is use HDR/environment lighting.

You could try [this addon](http://www.blendernation.com/2014/10/03/blightstudio-adds-easy-hdr-light-setup/), or use HDR panoramas such as [these](http://adaptivesamples.com/category/hdr-panos/) as environment textures.

To do this, add a HDR environment texture to the world surface (1) and (2) (it doesn't matter whether you add it in the node editor or the properties editor). There are no lamps in the image below:

[image]

Also remember to enable *Multiple importance sample* (3) when using environment textures, otherwise you will probably get a lot of noise.

Comment: Three point lighting is the way to go, not just randomly placing lights...

Comment: @someonewithpc Ideally you would make a specialized light setup which suits your scene or model, these are just some ways to quickly have some light so you can see :P