# Material: imitate a glossy ceramic tile

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to imitate the material (and glossiness) of a **ceramic glossy tile** as shown below:

[image: Tiles Example Large]

[image: Tile Example Closeup]

The following picture is where I have gotten to now, but I'm not satisfied at all with the results.

[image: Current material preview]

I've tried many things in blender cycles, including normal maps, displacement maps, etc. I guess I need some more professional guidance.

Comment: Lighting is key with reflections. Poor lighting will make it look very flat and fake. Try and HDR environment setup for a quick way to get complex lighting. Also use the displace modifier, not normal maps.

Comment: Try also to add some granulation: one small noise texture set to multiply in the mix, one larger for mixing the orangy variations with the main green.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the best result you should sculpt the highpoly surface, bake the displacement, paint the surface and build a shader. This is a lot of work so when you have a reference texture you can do following in your favorite 2D app:

1. Remove any lighting from the texture. I used cloning-brush to remove the gloss and dodge-tool to re-light the shadows. You should get diffuse like this:

   [image]
2. Paint a displacement map. Go into 32-bit depth as you don't want mini-stairs on your mesh from not enough precision.

   [image]

   Always blur your displacement a bit.
3. Create a glossy mask:

   [image]
4. And finally a detail bump map. This will be only noticeable in close ups so otherwise skip it:

   [image]
5. Now for the geometry: Simple-subdivide a plane enough-times and apply displacement:

   [image]
6. The ceramic tile itself is matte bumpy colored surface with clear glossy smooth coating on top:

   [image]

   The Glossy shader takes gloss mask as color through curves to adjust the glossiness intensity. Do it like this and not with the mix shader slider - you want to keep the diffuse part constant in the shader.
7. Pick a nice HDR environment or setup some area planes around to give the tiles something to reflect. Here's a render with the reference for comparison:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks Jerryno for your clarifying mini-tutorial!

It's seems that lighting is a very important issue here.
Could you please let me know how you set up your lighting environment? I'm struggling with that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Christophe There is only 1 sun lamp and a overall neutral color HDR map. The reflection you see in my render has a cold bluish tone, but the HRD is warm elsewhere to keep it neutral.

Comment: @Christophe There is a good answer from Gandalf for lighting here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18223/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-have-a-default-good-lighting-setup-for-cycles/18224#18224